# Python 3: Compare two numbers and return -1, 0 or 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simple function available that compares numbers x and y and returns -1 when x is less than y, 1 when x is more than y and 0 when they're equal?

If not what is the shortest way to do so?

Comment: `lambda x, y: -1 if x < y else 1 if x > y else 0`?

Comment: You need to write this function.

Comment: Announcement about removing the `cmp()` in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was a `cmp()` method in Python2 that could do exactly what you require, however it was discontinued in Python 3. You can create this method likewise:

```
def compare(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
```

It has been mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).

> The cmp() function should be treated as gone, and the **cmp**() special method is no longer supported. Use **lt**() for sorting, **eq**() with **hash**(), and other rich comparisons as needed. (If you really need the cmp() functionality, you could use the expression (a > b) - (a < b) as the equivalent for cmp(a, b).)

Comment: Why was it discontinued, seems useful to me?
But that's a nice way to implement it, better than with 3 ifs as i (and Axe319) would've done it, thanks

Comment: @FireFuro99 because it is rarely needed, and when it is needed it's very easy to implement as you can see